# How to save an array using AdonisJs migrations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to save an array to a PostgreSQL database, but I can't!

```js
'use strict'

const Schema = use('Schema');

class UsersSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('users', (table) => {
      table.increments();
      table.string('name', 255).notNullable();
      table.string('languages', 255).notNullable().defaultTo('[]');
      table.timestamps();
    });
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('users');
  }
}

module.exports = UsersSchema;
```

I tried to save like a string, like an array and use JSON.parse(), but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share any more details about what's not working (errors, ...). Thx

Comment: you are not saving nor parsing anything in that code

Comment: Yes, but how to define an array to the database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your datatype is wrong, Adonisjs provides "json" datatype for a particular column.
Solution:-

1. Change column type from string -> JSON
2. In the model, set datatype of "types" column as "string"
3. How to write a query?

   a) You need to use a seeder to insert the data

   b) You have to write `beforeSave()` hook, and then using `JSON.stringify()` stringify your "types" so that the database can accept it.

   c) To retrieve data, write `afterFetch()` and `afterFind()` hook to parse your JSON string to normal JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for seeding rather than migration if you intend to insert data

> Once you’ve prepared your database schema with migrations, the next
>   step is to add some data. This is where database seeds and factories
>   come into the picture.

read more here: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/seeds-and-factories

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of `{table.specificType('columnName', 'STRING[]')}`

```js
'use strict'
    
const Schema = use('Schema');
    
class UsersSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('users', (table) => {
      table.increments();
      table.string('name', 255).notNullable();
      table.specificType('languages', 'STRING[]').notNullable();
      table.timestamps();
    });
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('users');
  }
}

module.exports = UsersSchema;
```